# Removing duplicates with original records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this good SQL code that is selecting/removing duplicate records from table:

```
WITH CTE AS(
 SELECT UserId, A, B,
 RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY A, B ORDER BY UserId)
 FROM Users
) SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

But it's selecting all duplicates without the original record. How can I select duplicates + their originals (+1)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want to use `count(*)` rather than `row_number()`:

```
WITH CTE AS (
      SELECT UserId, A, B, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY A, B) as cnt
      FROM Users
     )
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE CNT > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to see the original record along with the duplicate record, you can self join your CTE:

```
WITH CTE AS (
     SELECT UserID, A, B, rn=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A, B, ORDER BY UserID)
     FROM Users)
SELECT c1.*, c2.*
FROM CTE c1
INNER JOIN CTE c2 ON c1.RN = 1 AND c2.RN > 1
```